# Is dict() in Python actually ordered like OrderedDict() from collections module

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quoting from python documentation I have:

> Changed in version 3.7: Dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion order. This behavior was an implementation detail of CPython from 3.6.

[Link for the above documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict)

But the following code makes me think that it's not ordered:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d1 = dict()
d2 = dict()
d1['a'] = 1
d1['b'] = 2
d2['b'] = 2
d2['a'] = 1
print(d1 == d2)


d3 = OrderedDict()
d4 = OrderedDict()
d3['a'] = 1
d3['b'] = 2
d4['b'] = 2
d4['a'] = 1
print(d3 == d4)
```

The above code generates the output(for python 3.7.5):

```
True
False
```

Essentially dict() should show the same behavior as OrderedDict() from collections module, but it doesn't. Please elaborate.